# Copy a range to a virtual range

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to copy a range to a virtual range or does it require me to sloppily paste it in another range in the workbook?

```
dim x as range
x = copy of Range("A1:A4")
```

obviously I usually use the following code

```
dim x as range
set x = Range("A1:A4")
```

but in the above example it only makes x a "shortcut" to that range rather than a copy of the range object itself. Which is usually what I want but lately I have been finding it would be quite useful to totally save a range and all it's properties in memory rather than in the workbook somewhere.

Comment: You could write the range to an array and use the array. I think that would be the closest thing to a "virtual range". Can you explain how you will use this a bit further?

Comment: Sorry, what you mean?

Comment: @Kyle that is what I was thinking, only disadvantage is I would lose the copying of the other properties. (a)Maciej Los I mean to create a copy of the range in memory assigning it to a variable rather than just setting the variable to point to the range. I understand this may be impossible. So what would be the next closest thing.

Comment: Which properties do you need? You could create a custom class to store different properties as well.

Comment: @Kyle I like how I can use Range("A1:A4").value = Range("B1:B4").value and it perfectly assigns that property without taking too much time. Can I also do this with arrays to properties or would it require looping through each cell? (I am thinking about processing time for large ranges)

Comment: @Kyle To get me started in what I seek to accomplish I would just like to copy a range of formulas and then repaste them into that range so the formula's were exactly identical after I do my process upon those cells.

Comment: It would require you to loop, but looping through an array takes a fraction of the time as looping through cells. If there are a few properties you know you need, and others you don't or will stay the same, I think creating an array out of a custom class would give you a good deal of flexibility. If you need all the properties, including .font properties, copying to a new range and copying back may be the best way unfortunately. Although others much more intelligent than me may disagree.

Comment: What about a reference to hidden sheet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to copy a range to a virtual range?

No it is not possible. Range allways represents some existing instance(s) of cells on a worksheet in a workbook.

> Does it require me to sloppily paste it in another range in the
>   workbook?

It depends on what you want to do. You can paste everithing from one range to another, you can paste only something like e.g. formulas to another range.

```
dim x as range
set x = Range("A1:A4")
```

> But in the above example it only makes x a "shortcut" to that range
>   rather than a copy of the range object itself.

Variable `x` holds a reference to that specific range. It is not possible to made any standalone copy of a range. It is possible to create references to a range and to copy everithing / something from one range to another range.

> Lately I have been finding it would be quite useful to totally save a
>   range and all it's properties in memory rather than in the workbook
>   somewhere.

Again, it is not possible to save all range properties to some virtual, standalone copy of specific Range because Range allways represents an existing, concrete set of cells. What you could do is to create your own  class with some properties of a Range or even all properties ... but it will be some extra work to do.

Here some examples how to use range as parameter and copy it to another range. HTH.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Main()
    Dim primaryRange As Range
    Set primaryRange = Worksheets(1).Range("A1:D3")

    CopyRangeAll someRange:=primaryRange
    CopyRangeFormat someRange:=primaryRange

    ' Value property of a range represents and 2D array of values
    ' So it is usefull if only values are important and all the other properties do not matter.
    Dim primaryRangeValues As Variant
    primaryRangeValues = primaryRange.value
    Debug.Print "primaryRangeValues (" & _
        LBound(primaryRangeValues, 1) & " To " & UBound(primaryRangeValues, 1) & ", " & _
        LBound(primaryRangeValues, 2) & " To " & UBound(primaryRangeValues, 2) & ")"
    ' Prints primaryRangeValues (1 To 3, 1 To 4)

    Dim value As Variant
    For Each value In primaryRangeValues
        ' This loop throught values is much quicker then to iterate through primaryRange.Cells itself.
        ' Use it to iterate through range when other properties except value does not matter.
        Debug.Print value
    Next value
End Sub

Private Sub CopyRangeAll(ByVal someRange As Range)
    ' Here all properties of someRange which can be copied are copied to another range.
    ' So the function gets a reference to specific range and uses all its properties for another range.
    Dim secondaryRange As Range
    Set secondaryRange = Worksheets(2).Range("D4:G6")
    someRange.Copy secondaryRange
End Sub

Private Sub CopyRangeFormat(ByVal someRange As Range)
    ' Here only formats are copied.
    ' Function receives reference to specific range but uses only one special property of it in that another range.
    Dim secondaryRange As Range
    Set secondaryRange = Worksheets(3).Range("G7:J9")
    someRange.Copy
    secondaryRange.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats ' and many more e.g. xlPasteFormulas, xlPasteValues etc.
End Sub
```

[image: Sheet1]
[image: Sheet2]
[image: Sheet3]
[image: Range values array]

Answer (score 8):

I think this is what you are trying to do:

```
'Set reference to range
Dim r As Range
Set r = Range("A1:A4")

'Load range contents to an array (in memory)
Dim v As Variant
v = r.Value

'Do stuff with the data just loaded, e.g.
'Add 123 to value of cell in 1st row, 3rd column of range 
v(1,3) = v(1,3) + 123

'Write modified data back to some other range
Range("B1:B4").Value = v
```