# Return an AutoFiltered Range from a Function

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have a function like:

```
Function GetFilteredRange(ByVal id As Integer) As Range

    Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C20").CurrentRegion.Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:=id

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Rows.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Selection.AutoFilter

    Set GetFilteredRange = rng

End Function
```

A function like this doesn't seem to return the complete result. It only returns a range with one row, where two rows are expected.

What I did find out is that an auto-filtered result could have (or does have multiple areas). In this case, I checked if AutoFiltered range did have multiple areas, which was true (2 areas). So in order to return the complete result, I guess I have to loop through all the areas and add these areas to a range which eventually is returned as a result of the function. Is this the way to go or is there a simpler method?

I don't have to copy the range, just need to loop through the returned range to use the values of the fields.

UPDATE:

I have come to the conclusion that it is not possible (based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616373/copy-a-range-to-a-virtual-range)). Every range should be part of a worksheet. In other words, I have to copy the content to another range and work through that range.

Comment: Is the `CurrentRegion` actually getting the range you want?

Comment: @BruceWayne,  Yes, the currentregion selects the complete range I want to autofilter.

Comment: Where have you defined the String variable `WehkampName` ??

Comment: @Gary'sStudent, sorry my mistake. This is global var holding the name of the worksheet. (assume in this case the name of the worksheet is a company) but I will adjust the code. Thx