# Function to get end of xlFillSeries vba

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to build a function to return the end string/cell value of an xlFillSeries. **Is there any way to do it without actually writing to the worksheet and then selecting last cell? I want to avoid manipulating the worksheet/workbook
.**

Here is the code to generate the series:

```
 Dim SeqStart As String, SeqInt As Integer
 SeqStart = "XYZ100"
 SeqInt = 42 ' Function should return XYZ141
 With Range("A1")
  .Value = UCase(SeqStart)
  If SeqInt > 1 Then
   .AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1").Resize(SeqInt), Type:=xlFillSeries ' Will cause error if only 1 sample sequence
  End If
 End With
```

I want to utilize XlFillSeries as it handles odd data well, Eg: If my SeqStart = `A1B100` then I can't utilize Regex to strip this down to just numbers, perform math, and then put it back together as there is a `B` in the middle of the string. I do know the series will/should always end in numbers, but I've struggled a bit to strip just the numeric portion from the right hand of the string without knowing string length and or mix of alphanumeric oddities.

So I guess my question could be answered by figuring out how to strip numbers from right side of string and then doing math and putting string back together. The numbers are what increments.

Or, I would just utilize `XlFillSeries` but without actually writing to the workbook. Currently I did just set it up so that it writes to a "temp sheet" and then captures the last cell and deletes the temp sheet, but I wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: Your question is unrelated to xlFillSeries and therefore unrelated to its title. The code you publish is likewise without bearing on the problem which you describe as "figuring out how to strip numbers from right side of string and then doing math and putting string back together". That, unfortunately, isn't enough of a guide calculate a number resulting from disassembling and reassembling :XYZ100". Therefore I vote to close this question. It needs a complete and thoughtful overhaul, including some own effort.

Comment: Your inability to understand my question and give meaningful request for clarification does not diminish the clarity of the question. I added the update as an alternative solution, but my question is 100% about utilizing `XlFillSeries` without writing to the workbook. I have posted how I utilize `XLFillSeries` but it currently writes to the workbook and I'd like to avoid that. @Variatus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically talking about `XlFillSeries` there is no way to utilize it without writing to a Range which [must be "real cells".](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28616373/copy-a-range-to-a-virtual-range) Therefor the best method is to utilize a "temp sheet" and return the last cell. It may be possible to utilize functions to strip numbers from right hand side of string and then re-build string, but I trust `XlFillSeries` more and have resigned to just using a "temp sheet".

Here is my function:

Note: There are some custom functions that I wont include, but you can guess what they do based on the name!

```
Public Function EndOfXlFillSeries(SeqStart As String, SeqInt As Integer) As String
 Dim DestSheet As Worksheet
 WorksheetCreateDelIfExists ("XLFillSeriesTmp")
 Set DestSheet = Worksheets("XLFillSeriesTmp")
 With DestSheet.Range("A1")
  .Value = UCase(SeqStart)
  If SeqInt > 1 Then
   .AutoFill Destination:=DestSheet.Range("A1").Resize(SeqInt), Type:=xlFillSeries ' Will cause error if only 1 SeqInt
  Else
   EndOfXlFillSeries = SeqStart
  End If
 End With
 Dim lRow As Integer
 lRow = lRowOfCol(1)
 EndOfXlFillSeries = DestSheet.Range("A" & lRow).Value
 Call WorksheetDelete(DestSheet)
End Function
```